# Processing MySQL result in bash

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm currently having a already a bash script with a few thousand lines which sends various queries MySQL to generate applicable output for munin.

Up until now the results were simply numbers which weren't a problem, but now I'm facing a challenge to work with a more complex query in the form of:

```
$ echo "SELECT id, name FROM type ORDER BY sort" | mysql test
id      name
2       Name1
1       Name2
3       Name3
```

From this result I need to store the id and name (and their respective association) and based on the IDs need to perform further queries, e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM somedata WHERE type = 2` and later output **that** result paired with the associated `name` column from the first result.

I'd know easily how to do it in PHP/Ruby , but I'd like to spare to fork another process especially since it's polled regularly, but I'm complete lost where to start with bash.

Maybe using bash is the wrong approach anyway and I should just fork out?

I'm using `GNU bash, version 3.2.39(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to "fork out," as you put it, to the mysql command line client program anyhow.  So either way you're going to have process-creation overhead.  With your approach of using a new invocation of mysql for each query you're also going to incur the cost of connecting to and authenticating to the mysqld server multiple times.  That's expensive, but the expense may not matter if this app doesn't scale up.

Making it secure against sql injection is another matter.  If you prompt a user for her name and she answers "sally;drop table type;" she's laughing and you're screwed.

You might be wise to use a language that's more expressive in the areas that are important for data-base access for some of your logic.  Ruby, PHP, PERL are all good choices. PERL happens to be tuned and designed to run snappily under shell script control.

Comment: I opted for the fork method; I'm doing it within another script process (PHP). I initially didn't wanted to bring in other dependencies to my bash script which only forks out to `mysql` but it doesn't seem to be feasible that way. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

My example is not Bash, but I'd like to point out my parameters at invoking the mysql command, they surpress the boxing and the headers.

```
#!/bin/sh

mysql dbname -B -N -s -e "SELECT * FROM tbl" | while read -r line
do
  echo "$line" | cut -f1   # outputs col #1
  echo "$line" | cut -f2   # outputs col #2
  echo "$line" | cut -f3   # outputs col #3
done
```

Comment: what does the `-r` do?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192786/what-is-the-meaning-of-read-r
(it prevents backslashes in your mysql data to dissapear / act as escape character)

Comment: Avoid `echo` at the beginning appending like this: `cut -f1 <<< "$line"`

Comment: @victor your suggestion fails. It results in "Missing name for redirect." and "sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected (expecting word)", I guess your suggestion is Bash - while my example explicitly isn't, is it?

Comment: @Leo You are right, my suggestion is Bash-specific. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 5):

You would use a `while read` loop to process the output of that command.

```
echo "SELECT id, name FROM type ORDER BY sort" | mysql test | while read -r line
do
    # you could use an if statement to skip the header line
    do_something "$line"
done
```

or store it in an array:

```
while read -r line
do
    array+=("$line")
done < <(echo "SELECT id, name FROM type ORDER BY sort" | mysql test)
```

That's a general overview of the technique. If you have more specific questions post them separately or if they're very simple post them in a comment or as an edit to your original question.

Comment: Thanks, I think my specific question is: what I ultimately get back from the first result is a simply `id => name` hash, first I need to iterate over all IDs to get further data and for each further data I need to return that back with the `name`. Is there a way at all to work with such a structure (hash, dictionary) in bash?

Comment: @mark: Bash 4 has associative arrays, but I think you should probably do what you're talking about within mysql.